# how to generate xml report using python-green for unit testing and coverage?

Tags: jenkins, python-green

Try to use [python green](https://github.com/CleanCut/green) to control python (2.7.x) code quality, and integrated it within jenkins.

In nose, there is `--with-xunit` parameter to generate `nosetests.xml` unit test.

In `coverage`, it is possible to use `xml` paramter to generate like `coverage.xml` coverage report.

Both are very good to be integrated with jenkins.

Do you know how to achieve this in green ?

Comment: Sorry for the 3-month delay in response!  I set up an RSS feed for the python-green tag so that I get alerted quickly to new questions in the future, so (hopefully) this kind of delay won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Green does not support any means of producing xml output or integrating with Jenkins.

However, [subunit support is planned](https://github.com/CleanCut/green/issues/34).  Once subunit support is in place, you should be able to hook it up to Jenkins.